# Has a degree of convexity ever been defined?

Tags: convex-analysis, plane-geometry

My question is motivated by the definition of electoral districts.

One way of making [gerrymandering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering) more difficult would be to require that districts be convex. A broader approach to the problem was asked at [Mathematics solution for Gerrymandering problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3010276)

However, this is probably too restrictive and difficult to achieve in face of other restrictions.  So, a better solution would be to have districts "as convex as possible". For that to make sense, one would like to have a measure of how close to convex a non-convex set is, and then try to optimize some total non-convexity of a district subdivision. Has any such measure ever been studied?

The application I am interested in is $2$-dimensional, so specialized definitions would be welcome.

Comment: Distant relative: https://mathoverflow.net/q/187819/91764

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38772

Comment: A less distant relative: [Willmore energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willmore_energy)

Comment: I was thinking that curvature would have a role to play - requiring a smooth boundary is not a problem, and minimizing Willmore energy (under additional constraints) seems to mold the shape into a desirable form.  Thanks!